# Can casts be more performant than tagged unions?

Tags: c, performance, unions, flexible-array-member

I'm designing a classical virtual machine that will operate on some kind of generic, type-switched value -- now represented with a tagged union:

```
typedef struct val {
    val_type type;
    union {
        int            i;
        unsigned int   u;
        double         f;
        str *        str;
        vec *        vec;
        map *        map;
    };
} val;
```

I've found a lot of literature about this online and am concluding that this is a pretty orthodox approach to the problem. I'm wondering, though, whether performance could possibly be improved with an approach like this:

```
typedef struct val_int {
    val_type type;
    int i;
};

typedef struct val_str {
    val_type type;
    char * buffer;
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
};

typedef struct val_vec {
    val_type type;
    val_type ** members; // <-- access member by cast
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
};
```

Here, I'm reasoning that there is a tradeoff between the cost of an extra indirection for accessing the primitive types (as well as needing to perform individual allocations - perhaps helped by pooling), held against the memory saved in collections like `val_vec`, by halving the size of the currently-fat pointer it represents. I know the easy answer here will be "measure it" but I'm having trouble coming up with an adequately-representative model that isn't a full implementation itself.

Is there a name for this second approach, and - assuming that this will be managed carefully (but *not* assuming it doesn't cause undefined behavior) is there a widely-understood risk that I'm not accounting for? Which approach is preferrable here?

Incidentally, could the use of flexible array members also be used similarly?

Comment: How exactly are the values supposed to be stored in the second approach? Why `val_type *` instead of `void *`? Are you ever going to access a value of type `val_type` through that pointer?

Comment: Is a `val_vec` supposed to be a homogeneous vector, or is it supposed to support mixed element types?

Comment: It depends . I would advice godbolt test for the particular case. You will see what is generated.

Comment: @user2357112 AFAIK (reductively), the specification gives that these kinds of casts are only safe between `struct`s whose first members are the same. So, by storing the members as their type tag, we can switch on it and then cast directly to the appropriate type.

Comment: @user2357112 The values of the vector (and other such containers) are enumerated in the `union`.

Comment: @MaxVu: That doesn't work with the vector structure you've chosen. There's no room between `members[0]` and `members[1]` to store the rest of the data an element needs, not to mention the strict aliasing violations.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, you're right. I've corrected the hypothetical code to reflect that the containers should carry _pointers_ to these separately-allocated and heterogeneous members.

Comment: With the fix, this is very similar to the approach CPython uses to implement Python objects, and it's an entirely viable way to handle things. You lose the ability to store `val`s contiguously in memory, but you gain other things - for example, adding new types dynamically can be easier this way.

Comment: @user2357112 I will refer to it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the second block of code is incorrect as written and will give you errors about the missing declarators in your typedefs...

Answer (score 1):

In the latter case you probably also define

```
typedef union val {
    val_type           type;
    struct val_int     val_int;
    struct val_str     val_str;
    struct val_vec     val_vec;
} val;
```

and now you have a union type that can hold any value type.  Indeed, this was the common way of doing this before anonymous unions and structs existed.  When you have an object you know is only ever going to be a val_int, you can save a couple of bytes of memory by just allocating a val_int and casting the address of it to a `val *`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm reasoning that there is a trade off between the cost of an extra indirection for accessing the primitive types

[Premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) is rarely worth your valuable coding time.  Any change here is at best linear. 6.001 vs 1/2 dozen of the other.

One way or another may be better in your select circumstance, yet the more info provided to the compiler, the more likely it will optimize better than you can here.

Code for clarity, which is usually avoiding casts.

The alternative lacks details and is likely problematic given the usual *incorrect* assumptions: `void *` or `val_type *` is a universal pointer, pointers to FP convert nicely to other pointers, alignments casted  is sufficient for other types, anti-aliasing is not a concern.